# Can you use 好き about someone else's feelings?

Tags: grammar

I'm aware that one can't normally talk directly about others' feelings in Japanese i.e.:

> 母はすしを食べたい *
>   母が寒い *

should be something like

> 母はすしを食べたがっています 
>   母が寒そうだ

Does this apply to 好き? 「母はすしが好きです。」sounds OK to me but I'm not sure.

Comment: 好き and 嫌い are not an emotional adjective in terms of grammatical feature, apart from if you nevertheless include them into emotional adjectives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

母はすしが好きです is perfectly fine.

食べたがる and 寒そう are describing one's temporary appearance. You can think ～がる is like "showing signs of ～". On the other hand, ～が好き is a simple fact rather than a temporary "sign".

Answer (score 0):

The sentence should be correct. In the basics of Tae Kim's guide, when introducing adjectives, one of the examples given is:

> ボブは魚が好きだ。

Which corresponds  well to your example.